# django testing problems

Tags: django, unit-testing

This is my view that I want to be tested.

```
def logIn(request):
    """
    This method will log in user using  username or email
    """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LogInForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['name'],password=form.cleaned_data['password'])
            if user:
                login(request,user)
                return redirect('uindex')
            else:
                error = "Nie prawidlowy login lub haslo.Upewnij sie ze wpisales prawidlowe dane"
    else:
        form = LogInForm(auto_id=False)
    return render_to_response('login.html',locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And here's the test

```
class LoginTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client  = Client()
    def test_response_for_get(self):
        response =  self.client.get(reverse('logIn'))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    def test_login_with_username(self):
        """
        Test if user can login wit username and password
        """
        user_name = 'test'
        user_email = 'test@test.com'
        user_password = 'zaq12wsx'
        u =  User.objects.create_user(user_name,user_email,user_password)
        response = self.client.post(reverse('logIn'),data={'name':user_name,'password':user_password},follow=True)
        self.assertEquals(response.request.user.username,user_name)
        u.delete()
```

And when i run this test i got failure on test_login_with_username:

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'user'
```

When i use in views request.user.username in works fine no error this just fails in tests. Thanks in advance for any help
edit:Ok I replace the broken part with

```
self.assertEquals(302, response.status_code)
```

But now this test breaks and another one too.

```
AssertionError: 302 != 200
```

Here is my code for the view that now fail. I want email and username to be unique.

```
def register(request):
    """
    Function to register new user.
    This function will have to care for email uniqueness,and login
    """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        error=[]
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            if  form.cleaned_data['password'] ==  form.cleaned_data['password_confirmation']:
                password = form.cleaned_data['password']
                if len(User.objects.filter(username=username)) == 0 and len(User.objects.filter(email=email)) == 0:
                    #email and username are bouth unique
                    u = User()
                    u.username = username
                    u.set_password(password)
                    u.email = email
                    u.is_active = False
                    u.is_superuser = False
                    u.is_active = True
                    u.save()
                    return render_to_response('success_register.html',locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))
                else:
                    if len(User.objects.filter(username=username)) > 0:
                        error.append("Podany login jest juz zajety")
                    if len(User.objects.filter(email=email)) > 0:
                        error.append("Podany email jest juz zajety")
            else:
                error.append("Hasla nie pasuja do siebie")
        #return render_to_response('register.html',locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = RegisterForm(auto_id=False)
    return render_to_response('register.html',locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

And here is the test that priviously work but now it is broken

```
def test_user_register_with_unique_data_and_permission(self):
        """
        Will try to register user which provided for sure unique credentials
        And also make sure that profile will be automatically created for him, and also that he he have valid privileges
        """
        user_name = 'test'
        user_email = 'test@test.com'
        password = 'zaq12wsx'
        response = self.client.post(reverse('register'),{'username': user_name,'email':user_email,
        'password':password,'password_confirmation':password},follow=True)
        #check if code is 200
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        u = User.objects.get(username=user_name,email = user_email)
        self.assertTrue(u,"User after creation coudn't be fetched")
        self.assertFalse(u.is_staff,msg="User after registration belong to staff")
        self.assertFalse(u.is_superuser,msg="User after registration is superuser")
        p = UserProfile.objects.get(user__username__iexact = user_name)
        self.assertTrue(p,"After user creation coudn't fetch user profile")
        self.assertEqual(len(response.context['error']),0,msg = 'We shoudnt get error during valid registration')
        u.delete()
        p.delete()
```

End here is the error:

```
AssertionError: We shoudnt get error during valid registration
```

If i disable login test everything is ok. How this test can break another one? And why login test is not passing. I try it on website and it works fine.

Comment: you can use Client.login, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/testing/#django.test.client.Client.login, to test user logging

Comment: @Ashok: Client.login is useful to test views that require authentication, but in this case, Artur wants to test his *actual* login view

Comment: I can explain why the login test broke the register test: Before you fixed the login test, it was failing before it got to u.delete - so the test user already existed when the register test ran. The best solution would be to delete the test user in the tearDown method instead of inside the test. Alternatively use different usernames and emails in each test so that one failing test does not affect the others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#django.test.client.Response.request) for the response object returned by the test client says this about the request attribute:

> request
>
> The request **data** that stimulated the response.

That suggests to me one of two things. Either it's just the data of the request, or it's request object as it was before you handled the request. In either case, you would not expect it to contain the logged in user.

Another way to write your test that the login completed successfully would be to add `follow=False` to the `client.post` call and check the response code:

```
self.assertEquals(302, response.status_code)
```

This checks that the redirect has occurred.

Comment: The response status code for the login view will only be 302 if follow=False. When follow=True, the client will load the redirect url, so the status code will be 200.

Comment: so 200 code is response code for the page that I am redirecting to? In these case these 200 is for uindex?

Comment: yes. Make the edit I just suggested on Alasdair's advice, and see if that test then passes.

Answer (score 2):

`response.request` is not the `HttpRequest` object in the view you are expecting. It's a dictionary of data that stimulated the post request. It doesn't have the user attribute, hence the `AttributeError`

You could rewrite your test to:

1. use the [`RequestFactory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#the-request-factory) class introduced in Django 1.3 and call `logIn` in your test directly instead of using `client.post`.
2. inspect `client.session` after the post to check whether the user has been logged in.

### Why one failing test can break another

When you edited the question, you asked

> How this test can break another one?

The `test_login_with_username` was failing before it reached `u.delete`, so the user created in that test was not deleted. That caused `test_user_register_with_unique_data_and_permission` because the user `test` already existed.

If you use the [`django.test.TestCase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#testcase) class, the database will be reset in between each test, so this wouldn't be a problem.